# Can I paste full solutions to a problem such as the linked question?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I found a question that I believe I could answer. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117765/does-there-exist-a-subset-of-substrings-for-reconstructing-another-string)  But, I have what I could call a full solution [here](https://repl.it/repls/CornySubduedRoot).

### Question

Can I paste the full solution? And, if no how would I give the best answer to my ability?

Comment: You've been around for a while. What do you think?

Comment: @Raphael Seemed wrong to paste just code alone. Without explaining what it does. But, I'm familiar with python than math jargon.

Comment: If you prefer Python over "math jargon", have you considerer whether you are on the correct SE site? For posting answers, I mean. Not to discourage you, but mathematics _are_ a central part of CS language, in the academic sense.

Comment: @Raphael I'm gaining step by step. Answering questions I believe I can answer. In the meantime, I'll keep practicing code and practice algebra and pre-calculus. This site is a benefit for me (and others) to actually read source material before answering a question. (And of course, knowing that my answer is correct before posting)

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts.

1. Source code is offtopic here. You'd have to explain the idea behind and properties of the algorithm, and add *pseudo* code.
2. Copy-pasting appropriate (see 1) material to Stack Exchange can be okay, *if*

   - it fulfills all the normal criteria for a good post,
   - no rights are infringed, and
   - the quote/copy is clearly marked as such, with attribution given.

Comment: Ok, I'll proof-read my code just to make sure it does what intends to do. And, I'll transform it into pseudo-code with a good explanation.